# Sorting scores and names alphabetical, average, highest to lowest

Tags: python, sorting

Back again with another question about my project. So I've tried to sort my scores in descending order in my text file. However, it outputs a syntax error.
The filename is created above when the user inputs the class_name and so thats what equals filename. However, it outputs an error.

This is some of my code:

```
filename = class_name + ".txt"                     
with open(filename, 'a+') as w:                    
    w.write(str(name) + " : " + str(score) + '\n') 
    print("Your results are being updated ...")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Your score has been updated")
    print("")
    w.close()
if get_bool_input("Do you wish to view the previous results from your class: "): #The 'get_bool_input' will determine if they input yes or no and will either open the file or not.
    selection= input("Do you wish to view the results in Alphabetical order(A), scores highest to lowest(B) or average score highest to lowest?(C)")
    if selection == 'A':
        with open(filename, 'r') as r:
            for name in sorted(r):
                print(name, end='')
    if selection == 'B':
        with open(filename, 'r') as r:
            file_sorted = sorted((ast.literal_eval(x) for x in r),key=lambda z:(int(z[1]),z[0]),reverse=True)        
            r.close()
    if selection not in ['A','B','C']:
        print ("Error, type in A, B or C.")
```

How to make it loop back to the 'selection=' question? If A,B or C are not selected.

```
if get_bool_input("Do you wish to view the previous results from your class: "): #The 'get_bool_input' will determine if they input yes or no and will either open the file or not.
    selection= input("Do you wish to view the results in Alphabetical order(A), scores highest to lowest(B) or average score highest to lowest?(C)")
    if selection == 'A':
        print (alphabetically(data))
    if selection == 'B':
        print (by_score(data))
    if selection == 'C':
        print (by_average(data))  

    if selection not in ['A','B','C']:
        print ("Error, type in A, B or C.")

else:
    input ("Press any key to exit")
```

**EDIT**

Something like this?

```
while True:
    if selection == 'A':
        print (alphabetically(data))
    elif selection == 'B':
        print (by_score(data))
    elif selection == 'C':
        print (by_average(data))  
    return True
    else: selection not in ['A','B','C']:
        print ("Error, type in A, B or C.")
```

Comment: Not an answer to the main problem, but you probably want `if selection not in ['A','B','C']`

Comment: Yeah, same thing pretty much isn't it? And how would i make it loop back to where they input A,B or C if they don't type in A,B or C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first open, try:

```
with open(filename, 'a+') as write_file:
....
```

then the second open do:

```
with open(filename, 'r+') as read_file:
...
```

Maybe it will work

**EDIT**

Now regarding first your file parsing and the sorting methods, I came up with this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from collections import OrderedDict

filename = 'file.txt'


def alphabetically(some_data):
    return OrderedDict(
        (k, some_data[k]['scores'])
        for k in sorted(some_data)
    )


def by_score(some_data, descending=True):
    return OrderedDict(
        (k, sum(some_data[k]['scores']))
        for k in sorted(some_data,
                        key=lambda k: sum(some_data[k]['scores']),
                        reverse=descending)
    )


def by_average(some_data, descending=True):
    def average(scores):
        return float(sum(scores)) / len(scores)
    return OrderedDict(
        (k, average(some_data[k]['scores']))
        for k in sorted(some_data,
                        key=lambda k: average(some_data[k]['scores']),
                        reverse=descending)
    )


data = defaultdict(dict)
with open(filename, 'r+') as f:
    for line in f.read().splitlines():
        name, score = line.split(' : ')
        scores = data[name].get('scores', [])
        scores.append(int(score))
        data[name]['scores'] = scores

print alphabetically(data)
print by_score(data)
print by_average(data)
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict([('ADAM', [2]), ('Da', [3, 0, 1]), ('Dadsid', [4]), ('Davd', [3, 4]), ('Dliid', [9]), ('Dloed', [1]), ('Dsid', [3]), ('lukedd', [8]), ('mathe', [4, 12])])
OrderedDict([('mathe', 16), ('Dliid', 9), ('lukedd', 8), ('Davd', 7), ('Da', 4), ('Dadsid', 4), ('Dsid', 3), ('ADAM', 2), ('Dloed', 1)])
OrderedDict([('Dliid', 9.0), ('lukedd', 8.0), ('mathe', 8.0), ('Dadsid', 4.0), ('Davd', 3.5), ('Dsid', 3.0), ('ADAM', 2.0), ('Da', 1.3333333333333333), ('Dloed', 1.0)])
```

Comment: Ok, so it seems like it fixed you read issue, have you exactly done what I wrote above? This hasn't been updated in your code. Now, you seem to have an issue in what you do with the data you read, which is another problem in itself. Can you please show us what the file contains on the line where it breaks?

Comment: Important info: I added few more lines with additional scores for the same users in order to be able to compute sums or averages

Comment: Thank you, very much. Added some of the things to my code and it worked! Would there be any way to make it loop back to the selection if A,B or C is not selected? Updated my code.

Comment: just put the selection inside a while True and break if selection in ('A', 'B', 'C')

Comment: is there any chance you could explain to me what those functions thats sort my file in different ways do in detail please? Thank you